The ROS build system is confusing
1)What are types of build tools and build systems in ROS 2 ?
2)What are the differences of Colcon & Ament ?
3)When is CMake used ?
4)Can we use Cargo/Pip for building ?
5)How does the ROS build system actually work ?

I agree the build ecosystem is quite confusing, let me see if I can answer your questions.

Build tools coordinate a build between multiple packages, build systems build individual packages. I suggest you read: https://design.ros2.org/articles/build_tool.html, it was very helpful when I started using Colcon as it describes the motivation. Catkin existed in ROS1 (and still exists a bit in ROS2), as well as ament_tools, and now Colcon. These could all be referred to as "build tools."

Ament could mean a lot of things. There is ament_tools the build tool, as well as ament_python and ament_cpp which are build systems for their respective languages. The difference between Ament and Colcon is that Colcon is only a build tool, whereas Ament is a project that provides both build tools and build systems.

CMake is used inside ament_cpp. ament_cpp is just a wrapper around CMake with some nice-to-have macros / functions. Both ament_cpp and CMake can be thought of as build tools. ament_cpp is the wrapper that let's it work nicely with ROS.

ament_python wraps setuptools from Python, I think you would need to do a little legwork to get a Pip Package from here. Reading how setuptools itself does Pip Packaging would be a must: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/. Once you setup building a wheel, you would need it to re-generate on every build and then it would be created with colcon build.
b) Cargo is supported with colcon-cargo: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cargo

Not sure I can fully answer this one, but I will give it a shot. For this explanation I am guessing you mean "How does Colcon work / interact with the underlying build systems?" Colcon reads the package.xml file in every ROS package and creates a "dependency graph" which dictates the order in which packages must be built. Colcon iterates through this graph invoking the correct build system on each individual package, such as ament_cpp or ament_python. Those systems will do the heavy lifting of actually building the package.


The build ecosystem is complex and takes time to fully understand and appreciate (I am still learning)!
The reason it makes little sense at first look is because it has been evolving for many years.  Each new tool tries to answer a piece of the build puzzle better than its predecessor. Which, leads to a fragmented set of tools that have similar functionality but not strictly the same. Along with that, the new tools and the old tools exist at the same time, causing conflicting information about which to use.

Thanks a Ton!! Jack.
